# How to send data that a client can read with the inputStream of an HTTPURLConnection?

Tags: java, http

I accept `HTTPURLConnection` to service POST requests. I'd like to send a reply that the client can read via `httpURLConnection.getInputStream()`. The client just blocks even *before* an attempt to read, even though I do send data over the socket opened by the `ServerSocket` instance on the server.

CLIENT

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();        
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");
conn.setDoOutput(true);        
conn.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream outStrm = conn.getOutputStream();
outStrm.write(request.getPostContent());
outStrm.flush();
InputStream inStrm = conn.getInputStream();  // <--- blocks here. NOT on the read
InputStreamReader inStrmRdr = new InputStreamReader(inStrm);
BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(inStrmRdr);
String s = bufRdr.readLine();
```

SERVER

```
ServerSocket servSok = new ServerSocket(portNmb);
Socket sok = servSok.accept();
readStuff(sok.getInputStream());  // **reading from the client is fine**
OutputStream outStrm = sok.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter outStrmWtr = new OutputStreamWriter(outStrm);
outStrmWtr.write("hello");
outStrmWtr.flush(); // <-- this SHOULD unblock the waiting client read?
```

I'd like my server to send a response to the connecting client. The response is in XML.

Comment: 1. Maybe the client shouldn't block?  2.  Try reading the input completely, and closing the input stream, before writing the response.

Comment: @markspace yes. I found this problem. thanks!